# EF Core: How to get identity key value generically using reflection or keyattribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, entity-framework-core, odata

Good day, currently working on an existing system that has over a 200 lookups which are stored in the database, e.g.

```cs
public class FruitLookup
{
    [Key]
    public int FruitId {get;set;}

    public string FruitCode {get;set;}

    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Each lookup has a code and description accordingly and each has a strategy class to get its data and only the code and description is exposed as below:

```cs
public class FruitLookupStrategy : LookupStrategy
{
   public IQueryable<LookupBase> GetLookupData()
   {
        return this.GetLookupData<Fruit>()
            .Select(_ => new LookupBase 
            { 
                Code = _.FruitCode, 
                Description = _.Description 
            })
            .OrderBy(_ => _.Value)
            .AsQueryable();
   }
}
```

```cs
public class LookupBase
{
    public int Id {get;set;} // new mapping property added
    public string Code {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

`this.GetLookupData...` is just an EF call to select the lookup table. It exists in the base class LookupStrategy

```
public IList<T> GetLookupData<T>()
{
    return this.context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().ToList();
}
```

The new requirement is to expose the Id for each of these lookup tables, because codes can be the same, and we the Id properties will be mapped on our new front ends as the value expressions.

Is there a way to achieve this in a more clever way that going to edit over 200 lookup strategy helper files either using generics or reflection? Below is the undesired approach of adding a new mapping of Id to each strategy class:

```cs
public class FruitLookupStrategy : LookupStrategy
{
   public IQueryable<LookupBase> GetLookupData()
   {
        return this.GetLookupData<Fruit>()
            .Select(_ => new LookupBase
            { 
                Code = _.FruitCode, 
                Description = _.Description, 
                Id = _.FruitId 
            })
            .OrderBy(_ => _.Value)
            .AsQueryable();
   }
}
```

Comment: What is `GetLookupData()` ? Show implementation.

Comment: I do not see any mentions how `FruitLookupStrategy` is related to entity type. If you think it is not important - your choice.  But answer in small details.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I have updated to show the GetLookupData method. Hope this makes it clear and simple. This is just an example and the problem defination is how to create perhaps a generic mapping to get the Id property value

Comment: @DonaldN.Mafa Just as a coding suggestion, I would avoid using _ in your lambdas as much as I see.  _ is supposed to be for "discard variable" or, in essence, variables that don't need to do anything with.  General rule, if you `_.<Property>` something, it's no longer a discard and should have a meaningful name.

Comment: You have posted something that is not compliable, like `.OrderBy(_ => _.Value)`. What we can do here is only to generate `Select` automatically for all lookups if there is some common part (if any). Extending what you have right now is not possible. Also `IList<T> GetLookupData<T>()` is bad idea to return `IList`, return `IQueryable`, in this case we will not retrieve unnecessary data from database.

Comment: It's possible, but you already created manually all these `Select`s for `Code`  and `Description` projection, so you have to update all these places anyway, hence why don't you just add the `Id` projection there. It would make a sense if these manual selects did not exist, and are created automatically based on some metadata.